# Exporting SWF faster - Flash CS5

Tags: export, workflow

I'ld like to know how to speed up the SWF exporting with Flash CS5.

Are there any preferences to make the exporting faster? 
What settings and hardware is the best to make it as fast as possible?

Any tips are welcome. I'ld like to improve my workflow.
Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

There various issues that slow down the "compilation" speed. Having a better processor and video card speed up a little, but you have to make sure you don't have any unused asset and alwasys double check your font imports, videos, images, etc.